# Data model to map two "likes"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-synapse

I'm trying to figure out how to model a user-managed lookup table to map types of calls to other types of web visits.  Basically I want to associate a call to customer service about contact info change to web pages related to contact info change.  My initial thought is something like this.

This is SQL Server if that helps - Azure Synapse serverless, but syntax is less important at the moment than concept.

| id | call_topic | web_url |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Contact Info | site.com/contactinfo |

Using this I can find calls by the same person using both
calls.member_id = web_traffic.member_id AND (some join to my lookup table).

To further extend this model, what if I use basic "like" or maybe regex, with a lookup table like this? (using "like")

| id | call_topic | web_url |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Contact% | site.com/contact% |

You might read this as "any call topic that starts with 'Contact' and any web_url that starts with 'site.com/contact'".  But I don't know what this join looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the "like" operator or regular expressions to perform pattern matching for joining your lookup table, you can proceed with LIKE to match the call topic and web URL patterns defined in the lookup table:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM calls
LEFT JOIN web_traffic ON calls.member_id = web_traffic.member_id
LEFT JOIN lookup_table ON calls.call_topic LIKE lookup_table.call_topic
                   AND web_traffic.web_url LIKE lookup_table.web_url
```

If you want to use regular expressions for more complex pattern matching, you can make use of the `LIKE` operator with the `ESCAPE` clause and define your regular expression patterns:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM calls
LEFT JOIN web_traffic ON calls.member_id = web_traffic.member_id
LEFT JOIN lookup_table ON calls.call_topic LIKE lookup_table.call_topic ESCAPE '!'
                   AND web_traffic.web_url LIKE lookup_table.web_url ESCAPE '!'
```

Comment: This is fantastic.  Isn't it going to be expensive in terms of performance?  I have both an Azure Synapse Analytics dedicated traditional SQL pool and also serverless.

And the escape '|' is really all I have to do to use regex instead of standard % _ characters?

Comment: Using the LIKE operator with wildcards (%) and underscores (_) can be less performant compared to using regular expressions for pattern matching. Regular expressions offer more flexibility and power in defining complex patterns, but they can also be more resource-intensive.

Comment: Regarding the ESCAPE clause, the pipe character (|) is not the default escape character in T-SQL. By default, the backslash () character is used as the escape character in T-SQL's LIKE operator. If you want to use a different escape character, such as the pipe character, you need to explicitly specify it using the ESCAPE clause in your query.

Comment: In terms of performance, the impact of using regular expressions will depend on the size of your tables, the complexity of the patterns, and the overall workload on your Azure Synapse Analytics environment. Regular expressions can be slower than simple pattern matching with wildcards.